# Determining continuity in a trigonometric function

Tags: continuity

Let
$$
f(x) = \begin{cases}
\sin(x)&\text{if $x$ is rational}\\
1-2\cos(x)&\text{otherwise}
\end{cases}
$$

We have to comment on the continuity of the function. Whether it is continuous at infinite points, one point or nowhere

My approach: 
I solved $\sin x=1-2\cos x$ and found that there were infinitely many solutions. But  in this case where the function is defined differently for rational and irrational x does equality imply continuity?

Comment: "Comment"?  What's the real problem you're trying to solve?

Comment: @DavidG.Stork We have to comment on the continuity of the function. Whether it is continuous at infinite points, one point or nowhere.

Comment: Then pose your question as such.  "Comment" is incredibly vague and unhelpful.  "Is $f(x)$ continuous at all points, one point, or no point?" would have helped.

Comment: I edited the question

Answer (score 3):

Yes, the function
$$f(x)=\begin{cases}\sin(x)&\text{ if $x$ is rational,}\\
1-2\cos(x) &\text{ if $x$ is rational.}
\end{cases}$$
is continuous at $x$ if and only if $\sin(x)=1-2\cos(x)$. The set of   solutions is infinite but [discrete](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/DiscreteSet.html), so nothing to worry about.

The continuity at such points follows from the continuity of the functions $\sin(x)$ and $1-2\cos(x)$.

To show that $f$ is not continuous when the equation is not satisfied use the fact that for any real number $x$ there exists a sequence of irrationals $(y_n)_n$ and there exists a sequence of rationals $(z_n)_n$ such $y_n\to x$ and $z_n\to x$. Then
$$\lim_{n\to\infty}f(z_n)=\lim_{n\to\infty}\sin(z_n)=\sin(x)\not=1-2\cos(x)=\lim_{n\to\infty}(1-2\cos(y_n))=\lim_{n\to\infty}f(y_n).$$